# jquery Datatable export buttons not appearing when set more than one datatable

Tags: datatables, export-to-csv

Export buttons work when i have a single one, but when i duplicate it, the buttons disappear.

I'm loading:

- jquery.dataTables.min.css
- jquery.dataTables.min.js
- buttons.dataTables.min.css
- buttons.dataTables.min.js
- buttons.flash.min.js
- buttons.html5.min.js
- buttons.print.min.js

as i read on the doc (official webpage).

When i've a single one (doesn't matter which) it works well, but when i set both dataTables on the same page the buttons are not shown.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $('#firstTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'print'
            ]
        } );
        $('#secondTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'print'
            ]
        } );
    });
```

I think it's due to a cannot set _DT_CellIndex of undefined, which i already tried to fix but it seems that it wants to persist.
Both tables are generated dynamically and some cell may be empty.

I couldn't find a way to tell datatables that allow/ignore white cells.
By the way, seems that adding an   on void cell does not take effect.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I found that sometimes a void  were loaded.
it happened on both tables but don't know why the buttons disappear only when both were loaded.

I added a class to  elements and then:

```
$('.rowToCheck').each(function (i){
    if($(this).children().length == 0){
        $(this).remove();
    }
 });
```

inside $(document).ready and before the dataTables init.

There's no _DT_CellIndex of undefined error and the buttons are shown properly now.